# Print simple text to printer RPP02

Tags: ios, swift, printing

I need to print from iPad device to printer (RPP02). I have read many question regarding this case but I still cannot print to my printer.
I create simple project, scanning then print with button.

• Printer that I used is RPP02 model (mine using VRTEC Printer Thermal). It support with my android project, and I read some question the printer must have BL 4.0.

• I doubt that I have correct `CBCharacteristic` or something but I do not know exactly.

```
import UIKit
import CoreBluetooth

fileprivate func < <T : Comparable>(lhs: T?, rhs: T?) -> Bool {
  switch (lhs, rhs) {
  case let (l?, r?):
    return l < r
  case (nil, _?):
    return true
  default:
    return false
  }
}

extension String {
    struct GBEncoding {
        public static let GB_18030_2000 = String.Encoding(rawValue: CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(CFStringEncoding(CFStringEncodings.GB_18030_2000.rawValue)))
    }
}


class BluetoothConnect: UIViewController, CBCentralManagerDelegate,  CBPeripheralDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonTestPrint: UIButton!
    
    @IBAction func onClickBarItemClose(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    @IBAction func onClickButtonTestPrint(_ sender: UIButton) {
        dataToSend = "TEST PRINT GOOOOO".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
        sendDataIndex = 0
        sendData()
        
        let line = "FORMFEED"
        peripheral?.writeValue(line.data(using: .utf8)!, for: service.characteristics![3], type: .withResponse)
        peripheral?.writeValue(line.data(using: String.GBEncoding.GB_18030_2000)!, for: service.characteristics![3], type: .withResponse)
        peripheral?.writeValue(Data(Array(line.utf8)), for: service.characteristics![3], type: .withResponse)

    }
    
    var centralManager: CBCentralManager!
    var peripheral: CBPeripheral!
    var service: CBService!
    var characteristic: CBCharacteristic!

    var dataPeripheral: [CBPeripheral] = [CBPeripheral]()
    var dataPrinterDevice: [Any] = [Any]()

    var bluetoothAvailable = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: .main)
        
        self.tableView.delegate = self
        self.tableView.dataSource = self
    }
    
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        self.centralManager.stopScan()
    }
    

    // MARK: - Table View Delegate
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.dataPrinterDevice.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DevicePrinterCell", for: indexPath)
        return cell
    }
    
//    // MARK: - Central Manager Delegate
    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDisconnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, error: Error?) {
        print("disconnect \(String(describing: peripheral.name))")
    }

    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
        if (!self.dataPeripheral.contains(peripheral)) {
            if (String(describing: peripheral.name) != "nil" || peripheral.name != nil) {
                if let power = advertisementData[CBAdvertisementDataTxPowerLevelKey] as? Double {
                    guard let uniqueIDs = advertisementData[CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey] as? [CBUUID], let uniqueID = uniqueIDs.last  else { return }

                    var objPeripheral: [AnyHashable: Any] = [AnyHashable: Any]()
                    objPeripheral.updateValue(power, forKey: "power")
                    objPeripheral.updateValue(peripheral.name!, forKey: "name")
                    objPeripheral.updateValue(uniqueID.uuidString, forKey: "uuid")

                    self.dataPeripheral.append(peripheral)
                    self.dataPrinterDevice.append(objPeripheral)
                    self.tableView.reloadData()

                    print("Name : ", peripheral.name!)
                    print("UUID : ", uniqueID.uuidString)
                    
                    self.centralManager?.connect(peripheral, options: nil)
                }
            }
        }

    }

    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
        print("Checking state")
        switch (central.state) {
            case .poweredOn:
                print("CoreBluetooth BLE hardware is powered on and ready")
                self.bluetoothAvailable = true;

            @unknown default:
                print("Central State None Of The Above")
        }


        if bluetoothAvailable == true {
            self.discoverDevices()
        }
    }

    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
        self.peripheral = peripheral
        self.peripheral.delegate = self
        self.peripheral.discoverServices(nil)
    }


    // MARK: - Peripheral Delegate
    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didWriteValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {
        print("sent \(characteristic)")
    }

    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: Error?) {
        
        for service in peripheral.services! {
            print("Service \(service)\n")
            print("Discovering Characteristics for Service : \(service.uuid)")
            print(service.characteristics as Any)

            self.service = service
            self.peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(nil, for: service )
        }
    } 
    
    func discoverDevices() {
        print("Discovering devices")
        self.centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil)
    }
}
```

Here my peripheral when I debug on button action click :

`<CBPeripheral: 0x28260dfe0, identifier = 2B2A97C8-F3A3-AD56-19C1-0CA2E011712D, name = BlueTooth Printer, mtu = 185, state = connected>`

And here charateristic from my service ;

````
<__NSArrayI 0x281800270>(
<CBCharacteristic: 0x28335f300, UUID = Serial Number String, properties = 0x2, value = (null), notifying = NO>,

<CBCharacteristic: 0x28335d860, UUID = Software Revision String, properties = 0x2, value = (null), notifying = NO>,

<CBCharacteristic: 0x28335d980, UUID = Hardware Revision String, properties = 0x2, value = (null), notifying = NO>,

<CBCharacteristic: 0x28335c480, UUID = Manufacturer Name String, properties = 0x2, value = (null), notifying = NO>
)```
````

Comment: There is only one service with read only infos, you can't write on it anything. How it's done in Android?

Comment: @Larme on my android project, the apps will scan pairing devices and show to list. when user click to rpp02 device model, the apps will connect to uuid which hardcoded ("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb") , then do the print using input output stream

Comment: Is that the only service you discover? That looks like the characteristics of the device info service. I would expect there to be another service with a characteristic you can write data to.

Comment: @Paulw11 yes, but as you said. I using another service that have different values. So I use this for print `peripheral?.writeValue(line.data(using: .utf8)!, for: peripheral.services![1].characteristics![0], type: .withResponse)` and the printer start printing. but I dont know if another printer device using charateristics on services[1] (maybe can on services[1] or etc)

Comment: You need to take note of the service and characteristic ’identifier` and look for those same identifiers in the future. You can't rely on the array index

Comment: @Paulw11 its mean i must add another uuid if i want support with another devices? i love to know if user can try their device on list then test to print

Comment: All devices of this type should have the same identifier for their services and characteristics, but when you deal with low cost devices like this there are no guarantees.

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57256836/send-data-to-print-to-a-bluetooth-ble-printer) has the same service and refers to a zebra printer (a "name" brand) so it is probably a commonly used service and characteristics.

Comment: @Paulw11 oh  I see. As you said,  I try with another printer (low cost) and some properties on CBPeripheral is not same with other (nil value, etc) .